# How to create a tree of promises?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I'm trying to create a tree of promises in Ember.

```
        return this.store.find('session', 'session').then(function(session) {
            if (session.get('isEmpty')) {
                return this.store.createRecord('session').save().then(function(session) {
                    session.set('id', 'session');

                    return session.save();
                }.bind(this));
            } else {
                return session;
            }
        }.bind(this), function(session) {
            return this.store.createRecord('session').save().then(function(session) {
                session.set('id', 'session');

                return session.save();
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this)).then(function(session) {
            this.controllerFor('application').onLanguageChange();

            this.set('localStorage.session', session);

            return session;
        }.bind(this));
```

I would like to execute the promises as shown. Mention that there are also nested promises `createRecord(..).save().then`. Is it possible to do that?

It's not exactly a tree of promises here since the last one should be executed for both branches. It could be of course if I put those in an own function. So like this:

```
'successBranch'.then(function(session) {
   setSessionDependents(session);
   return session;
}

'failBranch'.then(function(session) {
   setSessionDependents(session);
   return session;
}

function setSessionDependents(session) {
    this.controllerFor('application').onLanguageChange();

    this.set('localStorage.session', session);
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Doesn't it work?

Comment: My life is a tree of promises...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the last one should be executed for both branches

It does actually! If an error handler doesn't `throw` an exception, the error had been handled and the promise does resolve with the `return` value of the handler.

> Is it possible to do that?

Yes! That's one of the core properties of `then`, that it resolves with nested promises.

However, you could simplify your code a little bit, as you've got a bunch of duplication in there:

```
return this.store.find('session', 'session').then(function(session) {
    if (session.get('isEmpty')) {
        throw new Error("no session found");
    else
        return session;
}).then(null, function(err) {
    return this.store.createRecord('session').save().then(function(session) {
        session.set('id', 'session');
        return session.save();
    });
}.bind(this)).then(function(session) {
    this.controllerFor('application').onLanguageChange();
    this.set('localStorage.session', session);
    return session;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: I read that when working with promises, you should place them behind each other and not within. Is there a way to refactor this code as such?

Comment: Chaining instead of nesting I guess?

Comment: Or is nesting not a bad practice in this case? Thanks for the provided answer though! I guess I overlooked something during testing. Really appreciate the refactored answer :)

Comment: No, a certain level of nesting is always necessary if there are different control flow paths. Apart from that, promises provide the *ability* to flatten pyramids, it's not strictly necessary. In my code you can see 3 chained `.then()` calls, and only one nested.

Comment: I think a synchronous example could really help here :)